# In Mate, Sending two or more requests to the server simultaneously?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mate

I'm using Mate's RemoteObjectInvoker to call methods in my FluorineFX based API. However, all requests seem to be sent to the server sequentiality. That is, if I dispatch a group of messages at the same time, the 2nd one isn't sent until the first returns. Is there anyway to change this behavior? I don't want my app to be unresponsive while a long request is processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/flexcoders/message/113759) thread will help you to understand what happens (it talks about blazeds/livecylce but I assume that Fluorine is using the same approach). In a few words what happens is:
a)Flash player is grouping all your calls in one HTTP post.
b)The server(BlazeDs,Fluorine etc) receives the request and starts to execute the methods serially, one after another.

Solutions

a)Have one HTTP post per method, instead of one HTTP post containing all the AMF messages. For that you can use HTTPChannel instead of AMFChannels (internally it is using flash.net.URLLoader instead of flash.net.NetConnection). You will be limited to the maximum number of parallel connection defined by your browser.

b)Have only one HTTP post but implement a clever solution on the server (it will cost you a lot of development time). Basically you can write your own parallel processor and use message consumers/publishers in order to send the result of your methods to the client.

c)There is a workaround similar to a) on https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/BLZ-184 - create your remoteobject by hand and append a random id at the end of the endpoint.